# help to understand a example

Tags: participles

What is the difference between these sentences and which one is correct. Why we use two past particle in first sentence.

> 1) He wouldn't have been pleased.
>
> 2) He wouldn't have pleased.

Answer (score 3):

In my (non-native) opinion:

There are two pasts in the first sentence, because, I guess, it's [type 3 conditional](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/type-3-conditional/) + [passive voice](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/passive-voice/).

- "He wouldn't have been pleased" means that if some scenario happened in the past (but it didn't), as a result, he would be unsatisfied (in the past).
  For example, "He wouldn't have been pleased if he'd broke his car".
- "He wouldn't have pleased {someone}" means that if some scenario happened in the past (but it didn't), as a result, he wouldn't satisfy someone (in the past).
   For example, "He wouldn't have pleased his parents if he'd broke their car".

If you don't specify *who* is not pleased in the second sentence (e.g., "he wouldn't have pleased if he'd broke a car"), it'll probably be the "incorrect" one.

Comment: more comments please

Comment: Roux is quite correct.  The first sentence is in the passive voice: he wouldn't have *been* pleased *by something else*.  The second sentence is active: he wouldn't have pleased *somebody else*.  The second one is not very fluent or idiomatic, because the verb *to please* is usually transitive; we expect that if "he pleases", then "he pleases *somebody*", but there is no object of the verb in sentence #2.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to interpret the first sentence as a perfect passive "have been pleased", but I think that "pleased" is an adjective here, not a participle. So it is parallel to "He wouldn't have been happy".

The second sentence is a perfect active.

Comment: I was thinking exactly to the same thing.